# KeyBinding (Enter) on textbox doesn't update model

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm-light

I try execute command AddTodoCommand when I press enter in text box:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TbTodo" Text="{Binding TodoTask.Text, Mode=TwoWay}" >
      <TextBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding AddTodoCommand}" />
      </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>
```

Method execute properly but property TodoTask.Text is null.

When I click button with this command model have value:

```
<Button x:Name="BtnAdd" Command="{Binding AddTodoCommand}" Content="Button"
```

I think before button is pressed textbox change focus and update binding.

How update model after enter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the default UpdateSourceTrigger for TextBox.Text is LostFocus. thats why you cant see the "new" value in your TodoTask.Text. one way to solve this issue would be to change the UpdateSourceTrigger to PropertyChanged

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the Textbox InputBindings, and change your `Button` xaml to use **[IsDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button.isdefault%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** property like below and Enter will work on any textbox for this Button and `AddTodoCommand` will be invoked:

```
<Button x:Name="BtnAdd" IsDefault="true" Command="{Binding AddTodoCommand}" Content="Button"/>
```

Comment: it isn't work. When i press enter then execute command but value is null (the same effect)

Comment: But your solution with IsDefault="true" is better then KeyBinding :)